# System.InvalidOperationException while checking null value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check null value of a cell. I'm getting this error hardly so I need some help about how to test this. Here's my code:

```
private void installBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText("program_names.txt", String.Empty); // Clear program_names file
    int num = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in programs_dgv.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

        if (cell.Value != null)
        {
          ...
```

How can I test and fix this?

Comment: Which line throw the exception ? Are you sure that it comes from the if statement?

Comment: this line: if (cell.Value != null) Yes I'm sure because it indicates that line.

Comment: When you debug that line, Is "cell" initialized? what is the message that come with the InvalidOperationException?

Comment: Yes, cell = {DataGridViewCheckBoxCell { ColumnIndex=1, RowIndex=0 }}

cell.value = 1

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value(v=vs.110).aspx says "ColumnIndex is less than 0, indicating that the cell is a row header cell." for why it throws an `InvalidOperationException`. Also if you use `as` you must always be aware that you might get a null returned and thus should never just use properties directly without a null check.

Comment: @JonLopezGarcia I can't remember exactly but the error detail was something about bindingsource.

Comment: Can't I just remove row header cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check for cell != null && cell.HasValue instead of cell.Value != null

Comment: You have to add what's wrong with `*instead of cell.Value != null*` why it shows error

Comment: Chris has added the reason why it fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try that.

Comment: This is windows forms right.! so.. use checks of (cell != null && cell.Value != null)

Comment: thanks a lot. I think this is better: if (cell != null) { if (cell.Value != null) { } }